# spring-data - multiple DB: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException No qualifying bean of type 'TransactionManager' available

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, spring-data

I have created a spring-data project (version = 2.5.5) with two datasources [GitHub](https://github.com/vscoding1988/tutorials/tree/main/spring-boot/spring-boot-multi-jpa). It works fine, as long, as I am using the interface `CrudRepository.java`. But when I am trying to implement my own DAO based on `SimpleJpaRepository.java` I am getting the error

`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: db1TransactionManager,db2TransactionManager`

[DB2Config.java](https://github.com/vscoding1988/tutorials/blob/main/spring-boot/spring-boot-multi-jpa/src/main/java/com/vscoding/jpa/db2/DB2Config.java)  (DB1Config.java is the same but instead of '2' the bean names has '1')

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db2-config.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.vscoding.jpa.db2.entity",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager"
)
public class DB2Config {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
  public DataSource db2DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> db2EntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource db2DataSource, Environment env){
    var em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    var va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    var properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
    em.setDataSource(db2DataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.vscoding.jpa.db2.entity");
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(@Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> db2EntityManagerFactory) throws Exception {
    var tm = new JpaTransactionManager();

    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(db2EntityManagerFactory.getObject());

    return tm;
  }

  @Bean
  @Profile("with-init")
  public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer2(@Qualifier("db2DataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    var populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db2.sql"));

    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);

    return dataSourceInitializer;
  }
}
```

[ProductCustomRepository.java](https://github.com/vscoding1988/tutorials/blob/main/spring-boot/spring-boot-multi-jpa/src/main/java/com/vscoding/jpa/db2/entity/ProductCustomRepository.java)

```
@Repository
@Transactional(transactionManager = "db2TransactionManager")
public class ProductCustomRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<ProductEntity2, Integer> {
  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public ProductCustomRepository(@Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(ProductEntity2.class, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public List<ProductEntity2> customQuery() {
    var query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProductEntity2 p WHERE p.name='special'",ProductEntity2.class);

    return query.getResultList();
  }
}
```

I would expect, that `@Transactional(transactionManager = "db2TransactionManager")` would select the right `transactionManager`, but maybe I am missing something.

[ProductCustomRepositoryTest.java](https://github.com/vscoding1988/tutorials/blob/main/spring-boot/spring-boot-multi-jpa/src/test/java/com/vscoding/jpa/db2/entity/ProductCustomRepositoryTest.java) (test to reproduce the error)

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProductCustomRepositoryTest {
  @Autowired
  private ProductCustomRepository sut;

  @Test
  void customQuery() {
    //Given
    var special = new ProductEntity2("special");
    sut.save(special);

    //When
    var result = sut.customQuery();

    //Then
    assertTrue(result.contains(special));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations and don't extend SimpleJpaRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Simon, I could solve the error, by following https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Changed my `ProductCustomRepository.java`to `CustomRepositoryImpl.java` and added Interface `CustomRepository.java`

```
@Repository
@Transactional(transactionManager = "db2TransactionManager")
public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepository {
  // no changes here
}
```

Then extend my main Repository with the interface.

```
public interface ProductRepository2 extends CrudRepository<ProductEntity2,Integer>,CustomRepository {
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).